# Would humans on disparate planets with little to no contact with one another continue to evolve along different lines?

Tags: biology, planets, evolution, genetics

Would humans on disparate planets with little to no contact with one another continue to evolve along different lines?

In this universe, humans left Earth a hundred thousand years before. Or if it serves the story better 500,000 years before; and went in many different directions looking for planets they could live on. 100 separate planets were found and/or terraformed, all very far from one another, and humans have lived on them ever since.

After that long a time, would they all evolve into separate species? Would time make the difference? Would environmental differences on their planets make the changes?

What I'm looking for is a scenario in which two of those cultures meet after hundreds of thousands of years (or more if necessary) and don't realize they are just two off-branches of humanity. Maybe later they find out through genetic testing or something, but at first they should think they are "aliens" to one another, not the same species.
Is this at all feasible?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142920/discussion-on-question-by-len-would-humans-on-disparate-planets-with-little-to-n); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TL/DR:  Not after a 'mere' 500,000 years.  In fact we should know that the other humans came from earth, if not what type of earth animal they evolved from, even if there were half a billion years or more since we diverged from them.

**Horsing around a little bit**

To give a timeframe for comparison the last common ancestor of all equines (which comprise horses, donkeys, zebra etc) was about 4.1 MYA (million years ago). That's nearly ten times the length of time you suggested.

Looking at equines they look similar.  You can guess if a species is equine just by looking at it even if no one told you.  After all you probably were never explicitly told a zebra was an equine, you just looked at it and *knew*.  That's because 4 MYA isn't enough time for a species to evolve into something truly foreign.  Any species that is split by only 4-5 MYA would look close enough that anyone familiar with evolution would naturally presume they had a close common ancestor.  Many equines can also usually interbreed to some degree, though their children are usually infertile, so humans split by 4 MYA likely could interbreed at least occasionally.

Now on the one hand you could argue that entirely different worlds would create such a hugely different environment as to encourage rapid evolutionary change.  To this I'd say that's true, if it wasn't for humans technology.

As it is we won't adapt to our environment, we will adapt our environment to us. Were going to pick worlds that are 'earth like' and use technology to make the worlds more earth like.  There may be some minor difference our technology can't adjust for, gravity being the biggest one we would struggle to change, which may be a driver for evolution but most of the potential drivers will be compensated for by technology.  In fact I believe humans on different worlds will be far less likely to evolve into different forms then ancient equines, due to our technology.

**Technology > evolution**

Species living in stable environments don't change, look at alligators which have stayed roughly the same since the time of dinosaurs!  If a certain form is working for your environment then there isn't much incentive to try out new adaptation and koinophilia - the instinctual avoidance of things that are different, like novel mutations, in mates - will result in the species staying mostly unchanged.  You need some sort of change in your environment, some massive pressure pushing a species to need to adapt, for major changes to be likely to happen 'rapidly' - and yes 5 MYA is rapid from an evolutionary perspective.  Now I definitely do not expect human's environment to stay static.  However, I do expect the exact opposite, our environment will change *so* rapidly, due to technology, that no one mutation will be favored long enough to spread through the population before the environment and pressures change again, which will ironically result to the same effect of humans staying somewhat static evolutionarily much as alligators have.

Look at our technology 2000 years ago vs today, it's utterly different and yet 2,000 years is a blink in the eye from an evolutionary perspective.  This means that technology is going to change faster then our species can adapt.  As new technologies come about new evolutionary pressures will as well.  For example right now car accidents are a major cause of death in first world nations.  This means currently there is a fairly strong evolutionary pressure to evolve to be able to process movement at high speeds and make the the sort of rapid decision required to avoid accidents.  However it will be no more then a generation or so before self driving cars likely take over and the need to be good at driving disappears.  The few generation between when cars became common and when we no longer drove them were not enough for natural selection to significantly change humans to make us better at driving.  The same patter will happen with new technologies, they will change so fast that evolution can't 'keep up' and since the exact pressures put on humans to survive will constantly change with our technology there will not be any one mutation favored long enough to permeate through a population.  In absence of a *long lasting* evolutionary pressure favoring adaptation humans will default to persisting their current form.

**There is no such thing as humanoid aliens**

Honestly given how utterly foreign any species evolved entirely on a different would should be if we go to another planet and find anything *remotely* mammal like the only logical conclusion would be it likely came from earth.  If your humans know that other humans traveled to other worlds and they run into any creature on another world that is carbon based with four limbs and eyes, no matter how bizarre it's appearance otherwise, the only remotely plausible explanation for such similarity to earth animals is it's from Earth origin.  The only real question would be what earth animal this one originally evolved from.  Of course that means DNA tests would happen almost immediately and our exact common ancestor being identified via DNA in less then a few years of meeting each other.  This is true even after hundreds of millions of years when all the humans look utterly different.

**How many billons of years can we cut that timeline down to?**

If you want there to be any noticeable change in your human species you need to cut back on technology so more stable evolutionary pressures can encourage adaptations.  If humans lost their advanced technology, possible due to disasters after landing preventing them from building the infrastructure necessary to support it, then a species reverting to swords and sandals level technology will defiantly struggle with the utterly foreign world they are living in and likely adapt to better survive it.  If both of the human subspecies regressed technologically and had to rediscover their technology then their evolving to look different is far more likely since technology isn't favoring stability of form, though again not nearly enough for a mere 5 MYA to make them truly foreign.

If you take that further and presume your human species no longer remembers they originated on another world, and thinks space travel only recently became possible for species on their world, the likely hood that animals from another world came from the same common decent as them would seem much lower.  I mean how likely would you buy an argument that dinosaurs built spaceships and now live on another world if I told you that since the creatures we just found on alpha centauri have eyes they must have come from something like dinosaurs?

If you make one of these two human subspecies non-sapient you would further make it seem implausible they built spaceships and flew to another world, and make the divide between the two human subspecies seem far more vast since humanity tends to define itself by it's sapience.

(Here I should mention that it seems unlikely human technology would regress this much and humans still survive, as any planet humans travel to would likely be so foreign that without a relatively high degree of technology to help us adapt we couldn't survive on the world.  The idea of evolving towards loosing sapience, and such a non sapient species still surviving on a foreign world, seems particularly implausible without either billions of years of time for us to adapt to the world or this new world being far more earth like then is realistic.  However, you get some poetic license here; few are going to notice and nitpick on something that trivial so I say go ahead and have technology regress if it serves your story)

So my suggestion would be both groups lost technology, one group's technology was so lost that they eventually became non-sapient.  Then when your one sapient species finds another non-sapient species that looks like them; but their certain didn't come from their home world - which they think of as being the one they live on now not Earth - they would be less likely to guess they came from a the same species originating on another world.

Of course the utterly implausibility of two alien species sharing so many similarities as any of our decedents would share should still lead to experts asking allot of questions.  DNA tests would still be expected to happen almost immediately, and DNA comparisons would be made.  The plausibility of the two human subspecies sharing a common ancestor would still be known from fairly early on.  The only real issue would be convincing people of how that happened when everyone would be making the equivalent of "dinosaurs couldn't build spaceships" argument.

You would instead get the sapient humans arguing the DNA evidence is wrong because it shows our last common ancestor as happening before humans even evolved on their home world!  at that point evolutionary experts will point out that we always knew there was an unexplained lack of fossil records, or any other records, of animals earlier then whenever humans first touched down on their home planet and suggest maybe these creatures are somehow connected to that pre fossil record time period and may answer some of the huge questions as to why earth-like animals seemed to appear out of no were X million years ago.  At that point things probably get political with religious leaders complaining that's heresy since everyone knows god created earth-like animals on their world back then and how dare you suggest otherwise etc etc.  Eventually scientists will realize the non-sapient humans from the other world have a fossil record that dates back to, but no farther then, same time period as theirs.  Then we get even more interesting questions about how two similar species mysteriously appeared on two worlds lightyears away at the exact same time.  I imagine the standard arguments would boil down to 'god did it' and 'aliens did it'.

Of course this still requires a time period measured in hundreds of millions of years - tens of millions of years at minimum even if you push things- not thousands.  Even then the possibility of common ancestry will come up almost immediately.  The only real mystery would be how that common ancestor could exist given what the humans know of their own history.

Comment: Before anyone says it Yes Star Trek: Voyager did an episode with the dinosaurs built rocket ships premise I mock in this answer.  It was terrible and it's understanding of evolution made me want to cry.  Some of the political debate the dinosaurs got into when a common decent argument came up could be used as inspiration I suppose.  However  If you try to claim a computer can just predict the future evolution of a species over millions of years I will personally come to your house and beat you with a copy of "On the Origin of Species" so hard your last common ancestor will feel it!

Comment: ‘No humanoid aliens’: I would argue that you should use different terminology here given the context. There’s no reason to suppose that convergent evolution would not produce aliens with a similar overall body-plan to humans (which is what is _usually_ meant by the term ‘humanoid’). They’re not likely to be mammalian (at least, not obviously mammalian), but there is no reason the usual traits such as bipedalism, binocular vision, and opposable digits on the forelimbs could not be found together in an alien species.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I fully understand your argument, but I'm afraid I have to respectible disagree.  Convergent evolution does happen, but it's usually for a single feature not an entire species body plan.  It also happens because species are sharing similar environments and more importantly have the same basic evolutionary building blocks to mutate.  What are the odds that animals on another world start with the four limb building blocks that is the basis of almost all animals?  That eyes are the primary way to handle sensory input? ...

Comment: Since these first steps in evolution were partially down to random chance, this mutation happened and persisted instead of that one, those steps will certainly be different then ours.  And without them all aliens on that world will share certain common traits we don't have, they use a six limb and primarily 'see' via sonar perhaps.  The point is they will all share traits different from earth animals that drive their evolution.  Plus their environment will be so different the human shape likely won't make sense, just a slight change in gravity or atmosphere renders human shape impractical.

Comment: Note that it's even worse for humans than for equines because our long lifespans require a low mutation rate.  So you might get some rearrangement of the pieces that are already there and changes in dominant attributes, but the odds of developing something so different as to be completely incompatible is quite a lot lower.

Comment: @Perkins I agree humans will change slower then equines even ignoring their technology, but I'm not sure I agree with how you described it.  Humans would be just as prone to mutation as equines, in fact since humans have slightly more genes then equines you would expect more mutations per child to occur due to pure volume of data copied.  The difference is that longer lives mean fewer generations.  Each child is just as prone to mutation, but you have fewer kids in a given timeframe and thus fewer chances for a child to be born with a novel mutation.

Comment: @dsollen Eyes have evolved several times in Earth life, and the ability to sense light seems to be so incredibly useful I can't imagine any mobile species in a light-filled area would not have it. Six limbs seems like more of an argument, but prehensile tails are rare and humans and many other species have lost a tail all together; we don't need another limb. Many species have dropped another pair of limbs, or all of them. I'd suspect that many species on a Earth-like planet with hexapod origins would lose at least one pair of limbs.

Comment: Tech evolution can be made slow if the population is contrived. For instance, if the planet only has 10 km squares of inhabitable lands, then the population will stay super low and the tech will evolve very slowly.

Comment: It's an open question until we get to observe intelligent technological aliens, but I would not be surprised to discover they were viviperous, bipedal, binocular, with opposing digits.  I wouldn't be surprised to discover they weren't, either of course.

Comment: Good answer, but the pressure of tech on evolution being negligible - not sure. Over long run - maybe. For generations in question - it is measurable. A couple of years ago a study was reviewed in many articles like https://www.sciencefocus.com/news/humans-are-evolving-an-extra-artery-in-the-arm/ that over some 250 past years an evolved mid-arm artery (vs. negligible thin vessel there) became much more common. Some researchers linked it with industrialization and further fine handiwork (even typewriters and PCs) as something that brings food to the table and favours well-supplied fingers.

Comment: Conversely, many sci-fi stories stipulate - and it sounds plausible - that e.g. many of "spacelings" (humans whose predecessors lived just a few generations in orbit or on asteroids) may be generally unfit to walk on planets again - because their natural selection (and further exercise) at least does not filter out inability to suffer higher gravity, including its impact on skeleton, muscles and blood vessels. Some of that may be compensated with training and diet or surgery (similar to how current astronauts need a rehab after months in orbit), something maybe not.

Comment: @JimKlimov I do agree I was stressing the point a little hard.  For instance since we can't do much about gravity I very much expect evolutionary adaptations to occur rapidly to adjust humans to the gravity of their new planet, growing shorter and more solidly built perhaps.  Evolution is always happening, but outside of the ones from gravity, or any other feature of new environment our tech can't adjust for, I expect adaptations to be subtle and not result in obvious changes of form, at least not 'rapidly', from evolutionary time scales.

Comment: For worlds gravity adaptation will happen quickly because it doesn't require a new novel adaptation, it can mostly use existing genes and just select for ones more favorable for the new world.  By contrast while I agree humans on a world will little gravity would likely fair poorly on earth due to environmental factors, we see that affect on astronauts, I don't think a few generations would be enough for evolutionary differences.  In my example it's adapting for a needed trait, in your it's loosing a no longer needed trait.  The later happens slower since there is less pressure for change.

Comment: My primary point is that while humans may look a bit different, if nothing else gravity likely will lead to differences in height and build, they will look close enough that the first presumption should be human origin.  I'm afraid I still need to disagree with @prosfilaes in that I believe a creature evolved in a different world would be way too foreign to be plausible it would look earth like so the presumption of earth origin would persist even over extensive time frames.  Though I do feel the need to point out 'eyes' evolved from the same shared eyespots, ie from the same starting blocks.

Comment: "carbon based with four limbs and eyes" this is a bit of a stretch.  Eyes evolved independently on Earth multiple times.  As solar energy is a great biological fuel source, photosensitive chemicals will evolve, and going from that to eyes doesn't seem hard.  Carbon based is probably also a gimmie; Carbon is common, and its chemical behavior is great for complex molecules that life requires.  Even 4 limbs; symmetry is great compression, and once you get heavy 4 limbs minimizes limb overhead while giving you good support.

Comment: @yakk eyes evolved from light detecting patches which existed in most animals.  IE they were built up from a shared starting point, those starting points drive our convergent evolution.  I admit using light for sensory inputs is quite plausible, but it could be done in a multitude of other ways if it didn't start from the same starting point all our eyes have had.  That being said yes eyes alone aren't definitive proof of Earth origin.  My point was more we have a multitude of shared traits with all other earth animals, all the way down to using DNA to encode genes, that scream earth origin.

Comment: @dsollen DNA being used to encode?  Sure.  Mitochondria?  Almost certainly unique.  Piles of our low level biology?  Yep.  Carbon?  Eyes?  4 limbs?  Your examples aren't good -- **those are exactly the things I'd expect to be parallel evolved**.  Heck, I'd expect a completely alien planet to have crabs, but their underlying biology to be alien.  (only because all life evolves into crabs -- carcinisation -- with only a bit of a joke)

Comment: @dsollen  According to at least one research paper I saw a few years ago, lifespan and mutation rate per generation are inversely correlated.  Which makes some sense because mutations cropping up as cells divide in an individual tend to cause things like cancer, or simply organ failure.  And so the animal species that live longer (humans, elephants, etc.) are generally also more aggressive about weeding out mutations.  They have to be, or they wouldn't have long lifespans.

Comment: @Perkins You're confusing mutation in regular cells and mutation in gametes.  We only really care about gametes mutation when it comes to evolution since those are the only ones that persist across generations.  The study you are referring to looked at somatic mutations only, ie not in the gametes.  The leading cause of mutation in production of gametes is different then the cause of mutation in regular cell division and as far as I know there is no evidence odds of mutation in gametes is affected by expected lifespan.

Comment: @dsollen  That is a fair point, been a while since I thought of that study and the details are a bit hazy.  It might be interesting to investigate the gametes specifically in that case since, as our understanding of genetics increases, we seem to keep finding more potential channels for cross-talk between things we thought were separate.  Turns out RNA gets used in all sorts of interesting ways...

Comment: Physics major here: Fresh off my quantum class: If you were to even have a perfect simulation of the universe, you could not simulate the "for sure" future because of quantum probability. :) so accurately predicting millions of years into the evolution of a species, while you may get probable answers, none are definite!

Comment: Cats. Acynonyx and Felis Silvestris separated mroe than 10 MYA and still look quite similar.

Comment: great answer. one nitpick though; (and I get it was just an example) but even if our level of technology stayed the same for some reason and we continued to drive cars, the number of deaths caused by them is nowhere near enough to even slightly improve driving ability. Especially when you account for the fact that a lot of the deaths are people that are not at fault. (though argubably you could say that avoiding other people's accidents is a set of skills that could be improved via evolution too)

Comment: @Aequitas sorry but I'm afraid I disagree.  There are countless examples of adaptations driven by minor, environmental pressures.  Death by car accident are far more frequent then things animals have adapted to before.  For instance why did humans who migrated away from the equator lose their dark skin?  It was due to vitamin D deficiency it caused.  That's a minor hardship, plenty of black skinned folks live away from the equator today without taking supplements or facing major hardship.  yet numerous humans independently made that adaptation because it was a persistent problem even if tiny.

Answer (score 18):

> After one hundred thousand years, would they all evolve into separate species? Would time make the difference? Would environmental differences on their planets make the changes?

Short answer: yes

Long answer: genetic separation and different selection pressure (read environmental condition) are what leads to speciation starting from a common ancestor. Your setting meets both the condition, so it's fairly sure that, after such a time, there will be some divergence between the inhabitants of different planets.

However, for it to be sufficient to make cross-reproduction impossible is another story. You will probably need more time to ensure mutual sterility. Or you can use it as a story element, the amazement at finding that Gilgarious from planet A was able to conceive offspring after a fun night with Squawaren from planet B.

Comment: L.Dutch, I dont want it be so far that they cant reproduce, but far enough that the first members from each group to meet are convinced that they've met a truly alien species. And I know that it will take more than just differences in appearance. Cultural differences will play into it as well.

Comment: @Len If your goal is for the perception to be ‘truly alien’ with them still being able to reproduce, then cultural disparity (and linguistic disparity) is pretty much mandatory, ideally with loss of historical information about those other cultures (and languages).

Comment: @Len You don't have to go too far back in history to find people, even in the sciences, who believed that the various ethnicities of humans living on Earth were in fact different species.  Of course this was just a mix of ignorance and garden-variety racism.  But it doesn't take all that much difference in appearance to convince people of such things.

Comment: @Len Jesse F Bone wrote [The Lani People](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2509/2509-h/2509-h.htm)  (link goes to Gutenberg.org) which describes that situation a bit, though the Lani People are very humanoid!

Comment: I don't think environmental conditions will have any impact at all on reproductive selection. A civilization advanced enough to terraform planets around the galaxy are not gonna have any trouble with temperature/nutrients/predators/etc. cultural/societal values may change enough to have an impact, but it seems unlikely unless a massive change occurs. With such an advanced civilization it's more likely that one of these outposts will develop genetic engineering, which would obviously result in massive genetic deviation from each other.

Comment: @Len Ok you are both confusing me with your usage of the word "species".  My understanding, and I could be mistaken, is that by definition different species can't reproduce with each other.

Comment: @Michael:  It's complicated.  Only the most committed of lumpers would argue that _Panthera leo_ (_Linnaeus_, 1758) and _Panthera tigris_ (_Linnaeus_,, 1758) are actually the same species (lions and tigers if you are not a biologist), but zoos regularly produce ligers and tigons.  And then you get [ring species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_species) where the Lesser Black-backed Gull and the Herring Gull don't interbreed, despite there being a continuous sequence of interbreeding populations connecting them!

Comment: @Michael It would be more accurate to say a species is "two groups of animals that are unlikely to successfully produce *fertile* offspring in their natural habitat".  That means being able to breed to create infertile offspring is allowed, and being able to produce fertile offspring but unlikely to meet up and actually mate in the wild, as with most felines, also doesn't prevent one from being a species.  Still even then the definition is imperfect, for instance dogs can breed with any other canine and it's quite plausible they will meet up.  Species is often an arbitrary divide by scientist.

Comment: @Aequitas I do mostly agree with you, and say as much in my answer.  However the one thing likely to actually drive evolutionary adaptations on another world I can think of is gravity.  I don't think we have any tech likely to be able to adjust that and even small changes in gravity can favor different height and build.  Still +1 for genetic engineering as a plausible explanation for more massive changes.

Comment: @Michael My bad. I've been using the word very loosely. Sorry.

Comment: @L.Dutch Your answer was great, but dsollen went into more detail. Thank you.

Comment: @dsollen ah gravity is a very good point, which I missed. That is very likely to cause fairly significant differences in several organs as well as bone structure(s) (height, limb length/ratios, etc.). Though I do wonder what the range of gravity would be for human habitable planets. We can theoretically withstand up to 5g's, but 1. would that range be suitable for the entirety of the human lifecycle (namely young children/pregnancy or just super long period of time) and 2. would planets with a very different gravity to earth be unsuitable for colonization for other reasons?

Comment: @Aequitas I imagine we would pick a world with a gravity close to earth, even if we could survive on a 2G world it wouldn't be comfortable or easy after all.  However as I said even a very slight difference in gravity can be enough to drive evolution.  So even if we stay close to 1G there likely would be enough of a difference to drive some kind of change.  Even without novel mutations we could se a reprioritizing of existing genes leading to different height and build in just a half dozen or so generations with even small gravity fluctuation.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers have said, by natural selection? Probably not.

However that leaves un-natural selection!

If both societies gene-edit successive generations to be "fitter" for the environment, you can drastically change body shape over a couple of hundred years.

A large event could remove each civilizations knowledge of "Earth". Have one decimated by a super volcano or meteor strike, have the other do some weird religious or political cultural shift where they claim this new world as their own, and over 5k years simply stop talking about "Earth" (Where did we come from? Some say first people fell from the stars, and some were loved by the mother world, who gave them the strength to endure...)

After 100k years two superficially very different races.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how different the environment are and how long. If the human terraform the planets to all be earth clones then the evolutionary process will be slowed.

Also remember genetic engineering as with this technology can both accelerate the divergence or stop it completely.

Comment: hmm, your first statement I feel isn't that useful.  However, I do strongly back up your second.  If OP wants two human subspecies to be so different as to be foreign to each other in such a tiny time period as 500,00 years I think intentional, and extensive, genetic engineering is the only plausible explanation for how it occurred.

Comment: I suspect you could still get some  Deviations In 50000 years.  Especially if your colonies are populated With over representation of a particular mutation,  And that mutation was particularly useful, But still not this wouldnt be very much.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on whether their societies allow them to undergo a natural selection process or not.

Remember, that evolution depends on
**1.)** random mutations being advantageous to individuals (for some measure of 'advantageous': faster at hunting? longer lifetime? less cancer?) and
**2.)** this advantageous trait being allowed to permeate into the entire population by outcompeting the less advantageous part of the population.

It is certainly part 2.) here that would be under scrutiny from a conscious animal like the human. In our current state, society is wary of change, as we naturally become conservative when founding families, favouring stability for our children over wild social and genetic experiments.
Furthermore technology allows us to nullify any natural selection processes that would let a disadvantageous mutation die out in the animal kingdom, and amplify positive feats.

Summarizing, I think that modern humans have an effective speed of natural selection as a driver of evolution being decreased to zero. Any future, isolated society instead would chose their own speed of genetic change, either natural or artificial, depending on what they believe. They could chose to remain absolutely conservative, and disallow any systematic changes to the original genetic structure.

Comment: 'Society' was always wearing of change.  Koinophilia exists in practically every sentient species and will affect mate choice.  With the exception of domesticate species where humans now rule their mating behavior nearly every mammal out there shows signs of avoiding mating with those that are 'different'.  This slows evolution but doesn't stop it.  There is no reason to think that humanity would be any different then other social and intelligent mammals.

Comment: @dsollen " There is no reason " ... of course there is a reason and that's what my post is about. But of course that's mainly a story, as hard numbers on future human behaviour does not exist. As you hopefully understood, my main point was that I can hardly imagine (beneficial) mutations permeating an entire population, that is **fully aware** of those mutations. That's what is different in humans.

Comment: My problem is that the answer seems to be calling humans as special and different.  Do you think evolution can't happen in chimps or bonobo?  or are we somehow different?  It happened in apes despite koinophilia and can happen in humans the exact same way.  Each mutation would be small, with little obvious visible difference.  Over unimaginable long times (more then 500,000 years...) those small mutations would add up to something very different.  However humans wouldn't be 'fully aware' of mutations when picking a mate any more then a chimp is, it won't be visible and obvious.

Comment: Now I think an argument about mutations permeating a population being less likely in humans is viable, but *not* because humans somehow have a strong version of koinophilia then any other species.  I think our technology will change so rapidly as to result in changing and altering our environment faster then evolution can 'keep up'.  What mutations natural selection favors will be changing so fast as our technology does that no one mutation will have time to permeate because it won't be beneficial for long enough to spread before technology changes evolutionary pressures.

Comment: @dsollen: "Over unimaginable long times (more then 500,000 years...) those small mutations would add up to something very different. " Surely they would add up, but they would add up per pair that gets children, and not coherent on a population level, as no naturally given selection critera exist anymore. Future humans, relative to us now, would be messes of individual mutation lineages, as opposed to "step population replacements with consistent new genetic features". Add to what you said, there is more than one new 'unnatural' selection factor. Culture being another one besides technology.

Comment: [cont.] Look at 'famous people'. Ghengis Khan, or whichever popstar is en vogue at the millisecond. You bet those have more offspring than you and me(presumably non-famous, non-powerful), but whatever genetic expression made them famous and have lotta kids, the genetic basis for that will not consistently sweep over the entire population. This is because, until their kids grow up, their genetic expressions of the same 'successful' genes will not be needed anymore. 
Finally, that's similar to your argument.

Comment: If there were consistent evolutionary pressures on humanity then there is every reason to believe that mutations would spread and persist.  Now I will agree that isn't guaranteed because of the rapid changes caused by technology growth.  However I don't believe your premise that 'humans won't let it happen' makes any sense.  If you argue for technology modifying evolutionary pressures I'll totally back you up.  If you argue human will resist genes that were consistently evolutionarily favorable because we know how evolution works or some form of koinophilia as your answer suggests I disagree.

Comment: also how do you know that Ghengis Khan had more children then you or me?  For all you know I'm a giant man slut with a couple dozen bastards running around.  Hey just because I look like I should be a 40 year old virgin doesn't mean it's not possible!  Geeks need love too!

Comment: @dsollen: But there is no consistent evolutionary pressure, because nothing weeds us out, except for what we do to ourselves, by our own choice. Evolutionary pressures is the action of the selection process, just spelled out differently. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this point.

Comment: There is also genetic drift. Over long enough time spans even random changes which don't give any obvious advantage can come to dominate in a population. And given even longer time, you'll get enough of them to not be the same species anymore.

Comment: @PauloEbermann: What about Alligators then, mentioned in another comment/answer? How do they keep up their shape over hundreds of Myrs, in light of genetic drift?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I think the alligators from some Myrs ago don't form the same species as the ones we have today (and if you separated two groups that time ago, they now would be two species), even if they look similar.

Answer (score 0):

Given enough time, the answer is "yes"--[Darwin's_finches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin%27s_finches). I'm not sure that 100,000 years is enough time to produce different species, though

> [It is unclear when the line of Neanderthals split from that of modern humans; studies have produced various intervals ranging from 315,000 to more than 800,000 years ago. The date of divergence of Neanderthals from their ancestor H. heidelbergensis is also unclear.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal)

I have seen an argument that hunter-gathers are smarter (using an IQ test that measures spatial perception) than farmers/city dwellers, and that the latter are selected for resistance to zoonotic diseases (since our ancestors lived with livestock). Maybe different zoonotic diseases would give divergence.

Answer (score 0):

In Larry Niven's Ringworld series, he posits that humans have evolved to occupy many different evolutionary niches, as discussed in [The Ringworld Engineers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ringworld_Engineers).

That's a fictional argument for you.

Answer (score 0):

### I don't think they would.

The way evolution works, you have random genetic mutations, then if, in the given environment, that mutation proves beneficial, it 'spreads' and eventually most of the population end up having it.

The thing is, in evolutionary terms, 'beneficial' means it makes the individual either more likely to survive or more likely to procreate. Which means people without that mutation would be much more likely to die young than people without it. For humans, this kind of harsh evolutionary pressure is to a large extent negated by advanced technology (especially medicine) and social organisation. Most people will survive, even if they're 'less fit' in evolutionary terms. Now, your people have separated by colonizing different planets, so they were capable of interstellar travel, which assumes more advanced technology than we have today. So, likely, there wouldn't be much in the way of evolution of the species happening.

Now, it's possible that due to the pressures of life on different planets, these people would lose their technological society and end up with a pre-industrial civilization. But then, how would they end up meeting each other?

Most likely, starting with much more advanced technology than we have today and given 100,000 years, some of these people would become cyborgs, or would have the technology to store their consciousness in wholly mechanical bodies, or something even more sci-fi. Now if these people met (if you could even call them 'people' at this point), it's very possible they wouldn't recognise each other as human.